# Intepreting a m $\times$n matrix geometrically

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to understand the geometric interpretation of a matrix. For instance, I understand that a $2 \times 2$ matrix can be viewed as a combination of two vectors that define a linear transformation in $R^2$. This matrix indicates where a vector in the original space would land after being transformed, based on where its two basis vectors, say $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$, are mapped to. However, I'm confused about how this extends to matrices of other dimensions. For example, a $2 \times 3$ matrix.

Does this imply that the associated linear transformation is defined by three vectors instead of two? Does $2 \times 3$ matrix effectively map vectors from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. I struggle to think about this intuitively since its three basis vectors are two-dimensional. I do not see any indication that the matrix extends to $R^3$ without adding another spacial coordinate to the vectors. Moreover, would multiplying an n-dimensional vector (say $n=3$) by the $n-1 \times n$ matrix "compress" it and thereby transform it to that lower dimension with the appropriate linear combination?

Edit: It turns out that when we describe a matrix as being "2x3" or "3x2", we're referring to its dimensions in terms of rows and columns, not in terms of its representation of a geometric space.

Comment: Have you written out what a $2 \times 3$ matrix times a $3 \times 1$ matrix (vector) ends up looking like?

Comment: @Randall; Yes, it becomes a two-dimensional vector, which made no intuitive sense to me at first. But I guess if I think of it as bringing the vector one dimension down, it is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have understood that a $2\times 2$ matrix is associated with a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. This holds in general since **matrices are linear transformations**. In your example, if $A$ is $2\times3$, it represents a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> I struggle to think about this intuitively since its three basis vectors are two-dimensional. I do not see any indication that the matrix extends to $\mathbb{R}^3$ without adding another spacial coordinate to the vectors

I don't really understand what you mean, but I'll try to help you anyway. Intuitively, this means doing a linear combination of $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ (with $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$) twice. So, you don't need any other spatial coordinate, because they're still living in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and are then mapped into $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> Would multiplying an $n$-dimensional vector (say $n$=3) by the $n−1\times n$ matrix "compress" it and thereby transform it to that lower dimension with the appropriate linear combination?

Assuming that you see it as a column vector, multiplying  $n-1\times n$ and $n\times 1$, you get a dimension of $n-1\times 1$, so a $n-1$ dimensional vector. This is because you're taking a mapping that goes from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ written as a matrix, and you're applying it to the $n$-dimensional vector. So it will "compress" the vector, as you say.